# Create a pure HTML/CSS Book with flipping pages

Tags: html, css, checkbox, cross-browser, transform

So I'm trying to create a virtual book in HTML5 and CSS3 completely without JS which actually works fine but I don't want it to just look like pieces of paper that you flip over but I want it to look like a real book (at least as real as possible). So I try to show the book cover spine and the normal spine of the book on all pages.

I already tried to make the first page darkblue and bigger which didn't bring the desired effect. I then tried to insert a darkblue border and color the background darkblue accordingly which works on the first (and last) two pages and is also formatted correctly but as soon as I flip the page further, the top border disappears (but the bottom border stays darkblue).

Further, when I try to change the back button from its value right 13px to left 13px, the button then no longer works in Chrome. I also tried to use a whole page as a label, so that as soon as you click on a page, it will flip, so without buttons but that didn't work either.

Also, the back button in Firefox does not work on the pages "Lorem ipsum 7" and "Lorem ipsum 8". As soon as you click it, it displays "Lorem ipsum 2" on the right side instead of flipping back properly. But everything works correctly up to the Lorem ipsum 6 page...

You see I have a few problems that need to be solved. Of course, I also searched the Internet to find help or a solution for a few days, but I could not find any functioning solution.

I hope someone can help me make it look and function more like a real book.

````html
```

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My example Website</title>
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align:center;
font-family: sans-serif;
background: lightblue;
}

input {
display: none;
}
img {
width: 100%;
margin-top:15px;
}
h1 {
font-size: 26px;
}
h2 {
margin-top: 65px;
font-size: 22px;
}
.book {
display: flex;
}
#cover {
width: 400px;
height: 550px;
}
.flip-book {
width: 400px;
height: 550px;
position: relative;
perspective: 1500px;
}
.flip {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
transform-origin: center left;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
transition: 0.5s;
color: #000;
}
.front {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border: 1px #f0f0f0;
border-left-style: dashed;
background-color: #fff;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0 13px;
}
.back {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 99;
transform: rotateY(180deg);
backface-visibility: hidden;
background-color: #fff;
}
.next-btn {
position: absolute;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 4px;
bottom: 13px;
right: 13px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #000;
}
.back-btn {
position: absolute;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 4px;
bottom: 13px;
right: 13px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #000;
}
#p1 {
z-index: 5;
}
#p2 {
z-index: 4;
}
#p3 {
z-index: 3;
}
#p4 {
z-index: 2;
}
#p5 {
z-index: 1;
}
#c1:checked ~ .flip-book #p1 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 1;
}
#c2:checked ~ .flip-book #p2 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 2;
}
#c3:checked ~ .flip-book #p3 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 3;
}
#c4:checked ~ .flip-book #p4 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 4;
}
#c5:checked ~ .flip-book #p5 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 5;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="book">
<input type="checkbox" id="c1">
<input type="checkbox" id="c2">
<input type="checkbox" id="c3">
<input type="checkbox" id="c4">
<input type="checkbox" id="c5">

<div id="cover"></div>
<div class="flip-book">

<div class="flip" id="p1">
<div class="back" style="border: 5px darkblue; border-top-style: solid;border-left-style: solid;border-bottom-style: solid;">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 1</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="back-btn" for="c1">Back</label>
</div>
<div class="front" style="height: 560px; width: 405px; background:darkblue; color:white; border: 5px darkblue; border-top-style: solid;border-right-style: solid;border-bottom-style: solid;">
<img src="https://kibls.neocities.org/schachbrettwhite.jpg" alt="Chessboard white">
<h1>Poetry Collection</h1>
<h2>Lorem ipsum book</h2>
<h3>E-book number 1</h3>
<label class="next-btn" for="c1" style="color:white;border:1px solid white;">Open</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flip" id="p2">
<div class="back">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 3</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="back-btn" for="c2">Back</label>
</div>
<div class="front">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 2</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="next-btn" for="c2">Next</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flip" id="p3">
<div class="back">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 5</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="back-btn" for="c3">Back</label>
</div>
<div class="front">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 4</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="next-btn" for="c3">Next</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flip" id="p4">
<div class="back">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 7</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="back-btn" for="c4">Back</label>
</div>

<div class="front">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 6</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="next-btn" for="c4">Next</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flip" id="p5">
<div class="back" style="color:white; background:darkblue; border: 5px solid darkblue; border-top-style: solid;border-right-style: solid;border-bottom-style: solid;">
End of the book
<label class="back-btn" for="c5" style="color:white;border:1px solid white;">Back</label>
</div>
<div class="front" style="height: 560px; width: 405px; border: 5px darkblue; border-top-style: solid;border-right-style: solid;border-bottom-style: solid;">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 8</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="next-btn" for="c5">Next</label>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

```
````

Comment: Here's a pretty cool filp-book I created recently: [**HTML+CSS flip-book**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76972952/383904)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to fix the border problem for you.  You had some inconsistencies between your heights, some being `550px` and some being `560px` in the inline html same with the widths, some being `405` and some `400` I made them all `400`.  I also removed all of the inline html borders and simply added:

```
border-top: 5px solid darkblue;
border-right: 5px solid darkblue;
border-bottom: 5px solid darkblue;
border-left: 1px dashed #f0f0f0;
```

to your `.flip` in CSS (I also removed the border from `.front`)

Heres a working example:

EDIT: Removed:

```
border-top: 5px solid darkblue;
border-right: 5px solid darkblue;
border-bottom: 5px solid darkblue;
```

So that the pages don't have border on them.

EDIT 2: I found a work around with getting the back buttons working in Firefox.  I added this code to your CSS:

```
#c3:checked ~ .flip-book #p1 {
display: none;
}
#c4:checked ~ .flip-book #p2 {
display: none;
}
#c5:checked ~ .flip-book #p3 {
display: none;
}
```

Essentially what it does is gets ride of the "non-visible" pages and there for theres no overlapping and transformed checkboxes that cause issues with firefox and chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My example Website</title>
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align:center;
font-family: sans-serif;
background: lightblue;
}

input {
display: none;
}
img {
width: 100%;
margin-top:15px;
}
h1 {
font-size: 26px;
}
h2 {
margin-top: 65px;
font-size: 22px;
}
.book {
display: flex;
}
#cover {
width: 400px;
height: 550px;
}
.flip-book {
width: 400px;
height: 550px;
position: relative;
perspective: 1500px;
}
.flip {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
transform-origin: center left;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
transition: 0.5s;
color: #000;
border-left: 1px dashed #f0f0f0;
}
.front {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #fff;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0 13px;

}
.back {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 99;
transform: rotateY(180deg);
backface-visibility: hidden;
background-color: #fff;
}
.next-btn {
position: absolute;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 4px;
bottom: 13px;
right: 13px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #000;
}
.back-btn {
position: absolute;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 4px;
bottom: 13px;
right: 13px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #000;
}
#p1 {
z-index: 5;
}
#p2 {
z-index: 4;
}
#p3 {
z-index: 3;
}
#p4 {
z-index: 2;
}
#p5 {
z-index: 1;
}
#c1:checked ~ .flip-book #p1 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 1;
}
#c2:checked ~ .flip-book #p2 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 2;
}
#c3:checked ~ .flip-book #p3 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 3;
}
#c4:checked ~ .flip-book #p4 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 4;
}
#c5:checked ~ .flip-book #p5 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 5;
}

#c3:checked ~ .flip-book #p1 {
display: none;
}
#c4:checked ~ .flip-book #p2 {
display: none;
}
#c5:checked ~ .flip-book #p3 {
display: none;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="book">
<input type="checkbox" id="c1">
<input type="checkbox" id="c2">
<input type="checkbox" id="c3">
<input type="checkbox" id="c4">
<input type="checkbox" id="c5">

<div id="cover"></div>
<div class="flip-book">

<div class="flip" id="p1">
<div class="back" style="">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 1</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="back-btn" for="c1">Back</label>
</div>
<div class="front" style="height: 550px; width: 400px; background:darkblue; color:white;">
<img src="https://kibls.neocities.org/schachbrettwhite.jpg" alt="Chessboard white">
<h1>Poetry Collection</h1>
<h2>Lorem ipsum book</h2>
<h3>E-book number 1</h3>
<label class="next-btn" for="c1" style="color:white;border:1px solid white;">Open</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flip" id="p2">
<div class="back">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 3</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="back-btn" for="c2">Back</label>
</div>
<div class="front">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 2</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="next-btn" for="c2">Next</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flip" id="p3">
<div class="back">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 5</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="back-btn" for="c3">Back</label>
</div>
<div class="front">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 4</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="next-btn" for="c3">Next</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flip" id="p4">
<div class="back">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 7</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="back-btn" for="c4">Back</label>
</div>

<div class="front">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 6</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="next-btn" for="c4">Next</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flip" id="p5">
<div class="back" style="color:white; background:darkblue; ">
End of the book
<label class="back-btn" for="c5" style="color:white;border:1px solid white;">Back</label>
</div>
<div class="front" style="height: 550px; width: 400px;">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 8</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="next-btn" for="c5">Next</label>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 3: So im assuming you still want the border in the background, just not the pages when turned right? So what I did was add a dummy `div` with class `bb` and set it's `width` and `height` to the same as the book and set it's `z-index` to `-1` so its now in the background and give it a border only when internal page check boxes are checked, and romove it when the final cover is show.

This is what I added to the CSS (also added `<div class="bb"></div>` right under the checkboxes in the html)

```
.bb{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 800px;
  height: 550px;
 pointer-events: none;

}

#c1:checked ~ .bb {
border: 5px solid darkblue;
}
#c2:checked ~ .bb {
border: 5px solid darkblue;
}
#c3:checked ~ .bb {
border: 5px solid darkblue;
}
#c4:checked ~ .bb {
border: 5px solid darkblue;
}
#c5:checked ~ .bb {
border: none;
}
```

Here's a working example.  I really do hope this is what you're looking for

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My example Website</title>
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align:center;
font-family: sans-serif;
background: lightblue;
}

input {
display: none;
}
img {
width: 100%;
margin-top:15px;
}
h1 {
font-size: 26px;
}
h2 {
margin-top: 65px;
font-size: 22px;
}
.book {
display: flex;
}
#cover {
width: 400px;
height: 550px;
}
.flip-book {
width: 400px;
height: 550px;
position: relative;
perspective: 1500px;
}
.flip {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
transform-origin: center left;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
transition: 0.5s;
color: #000;

}
.front {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #fff;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0 13px;

}
.back {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 99;
transform: rotateY(180deg);
backface-visibility: hidden;
background-color: #fff;
}
.next-btn {
position: absolute;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 4px;
bottom: 13px;
right: 13px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #000;
}
.back-btn {
position: absolute;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 4px;
bottom: 13px;
right: 13px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #000;
}
#p1 {
z-index: 5;
margin: 5px;
}
#p2 {
z-index: 4;
margin: 5px;
}
#p3 {
z-index: 3;
margin: 5px;
}
#p4 {
z-index: 2;
margin: 5px;
}
#p5 {
z-index: 1;
margin: 5px;
}
#c1:checked ~ .flip-book #p1 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 1;
}
#c2:checked ~ .flip-book #p2 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 2;
}
#c3:checked ~ .flip-book #p3 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 3;
}
#c4:checked ~ .flip-book #p4 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 4;
}
#c5:checked ~ .flip-book #p5 {
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
z-index: 5;
}

#c3:checked ~ .flip-book #p1 {
display: none;
}
#c4:checked ~ .flip-book #p2 {
display: none;
}
#c5:checked ~ .flip-book #p3 {
display: none;
}


.bb{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 800px;
  height: 550px;
 pointer-events: none;

}

#c1:checked ~ .bb {
border: 5px solid darkblue;
background-color: white;
}
#c2:checked ~ .bb {
border: 5px solid darkblue;
}
#c3:checked ~ .bb {
border: 5px solid darkblue;
}
#c4:checked ~ .bb {
border: 5px solid darkblue;
}
#c5:checked ~ .bb {
border: none;
background-color: transparent;
}






</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="book">
<input type="checkbox" id="c1">
<input type="checkbox" id="c2">
<input type="checkbox" id="c3">
<input type="checkbox" id="c4">
<input type="checkbox" id="c5">

<div class="bb"></div>

<div id="cover"></div>
<div class="flip-book">

<div class="flip" id="p1">
<div class="back" style="">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 1</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="back-btn" for="c1">Back</label>
</div>
<div class="front" style="height: 550px; width: 400px; background:darkblue; color:white;">
<img src="https://kibls.neocities.org/schachbrettwhite.jpg" alt="Chessboard white">
<h1>Poetry Collection</h1>
<h2>Lorem ipsum book</h2>
<h3>E-book number 1</h3>
<label class="next-btn" for="c1" style="color:white;border:1px solid white;">Open</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flip" id="p2">
<div class="back">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 3</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="back-btn" for="c2">Back</label>
</div>
<div class="front">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 2</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="next-btn" for="c2">Next</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flip" id="p3">
<div class="back">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 5</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="back-btn" for="c3">Back</label>
</div>
<div class="front">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 4</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="next-btn" for="c3">Next</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flip" id="p4">
<div class="back">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 7</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="back-btn" for="c4">Back</label>
</div>

<div class="front">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 6</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="next-btn" for="c4">Next</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="flip" id="p5">
<div class="back" style="color:white; background:darkblue; ">
End of the book
<label class="back-btn" for="c5" style="color:white;border:1px solid white;">Back</label>
</div>
<div class="front" style="height: 550px; width: 400px;">

<h2>Lorem ipsum 8</h2><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br><br>

sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>
invidunt ut labore et dolore <br><br>

magna aliquyam erat, sed diam <br>
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam <br><br>

et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <br>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <br><br>

takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum <br>
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <br><br>

sit amet<br>
<label class="next-btn" for="c5">Next</label>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but in this way each page has a visible book edge, which I actually wanted to avoid. I only wanted to let pure book pages turn without having a visible border and only the first and last page should have a (visible) spine. So like I would look at a real book from above.

And it is a real problem if Firefox would not be supported. It has to work in all browsers. I mean Firefox has a lot of users, after all. Are there any -moz- parameters that can be inserted to solve the issue with the back button on the last two pages in Firefox that I didn't consider?

Comment: Oh so you dont want any borders, well then that's very simple with the code I provided, just remove `border-top: 5px solid darkblue;
border-right: 5px solid darkblue;
border-bottom: 5px solid darkblue;` from `.flip` in my example and it will work. I'll update my answer so you can see

Comment: @KiBLS I found a workaround for the buttons not working in firefox.  Take a look at my answer again and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @KiBLS sorry 1 more update, when you mean you don't want the borders on the pages, you mean you still want that border in the background though? like this: https://jsfiddle.net/fb7eu2ht/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it should be in the middle section! However, I now find it a disaster as the first page opens or even the last page opens.Because I see first the border and only afterwards the page opening. When closing the pages, however, it looks perfectly normal.But I think I can live with your second approach/result. Because that it is working in all browsers is more important than the border I guess.Then the book is more like a "softcover book".And softcovers are without a border.I can become friends with this idea/solution. Well then thanks for your help and have a great day! :)

Comment: @KiBLS 1 last go at it, check this out and let me know if this fixed your border showing up too soon issue. https://jsfiddle.net/fb7eu2ht/2/

Comment: Yes, that is better than the last approach but I see the page opening without a border and that both are separated is not the situation with a real book. I'm probably making too high demands on the layout.As I said before, I only thought of a softcover book where there is no border at all during your attempts and I find the idea acceptable. What would still be desirable is the back button.It would look better if it would be set to left 13 px instead of right 13px.But then the button no longer works in chrome. In firefox it works then, only chrome won't let me put the button on the other side.

Comment: not sure how to fix that chrome issue with the buttons, but what you have is working so I hope it serves your function. I'm not going to spend anymore time on this so I hope what you have now serves you well.  Best of luck to you and your project

Comment: Yes, as I said; it operates well and it's ok. I think I can continue to work with it now. Thanks again for your effort and I wish you a great day! :)