# How to make a flip page effect in book without using absolute position, or make a relatively positioned div adapt to content size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sabeser/pen/zYyvrZN)

I have a div that represents a book page and contains the front and the back elements. On a click the page flips to show the reverse side.

In order to make the styling work, I made the book div (which contains the page divs) have `position: relative`, and the paper (which represents a page) div has `position: absolute` styling.

However, the width and height of the `book` are set in px so when the paper content doesn't fit the dimensions, the content overflows:

[image]

On pages where the content fits, it looks alright:

[image]

How do I make the `paper` elements to adjust to the size of the content? So that if there are several pages, the height of each page would be equal to the height of the page with the most amount of content?

```js
let pages = document.getElementsByClassName("paper");

setup(pages);

function setup(elements) {
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    let previous = i === 0 ? null : elements[i - 1];
    let element = elements[i];
    let next = i === elements.length - 1 ? null : elements[i + 1];

    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
      element.classList.toggle('flipped');
      if (element.classList.contains("flipped")) {
        if (next !== null) {
          next.style.zIndex++;
        }
        element.style.zIndex = i + 1;
      } else {
        element.style.zIndex = elements.length - i;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #333333;
}


/* Book */

.book {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: transform 3.5s;
}

.paper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  perspective: 1500px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.front,
.back {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 3.5s;
  display: flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.front {
  z-index: 1;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-left: 3px solid powderblue;
  background-color: #b3ffff;
}

.back {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #ffd699;
}

.front-content,
.back-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.back-content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}


/* Paper flip effect */

.flipped .front,
.flipped .back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}


/* Controller Buttons */

button {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button:hover i {
  color: #636363;
}

i {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: gray;
}


/* Paper stack order */

#p1 {
  z-index: 3;
}

#p2 {
  z-index: 2;
}

#p3 {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="book" class="book">
  <div id="p1" class="paper">
    <div class="front">
      <div id="f1" class="front-content">
        <h1>The Roman Empire was the post-Republican state of ancient Rome. It included territory around the Mediterranean in Europe, North Africa, and Western Asia, and was ruled by emperors. The adoption of Christianity as the state church in 380 and the
          fall of the Western Roman Empire conventionally marks the end of classical antiquity and the beginning of the Middle Ages.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="back">
      <div id="b1" class="back-content">
        <h1>The first two centuries of the Empire saw a period of unprecedented stability and prosperity known as the Pax Romana (lit. 'Roman Peace'). </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Second page -->
  <div id="p2" class="paper">
    <div class="front">
      <div id="f2" class="front-content">
        <h1>Due to the Empire's extent and endurance, its institutions and culture had a lasting influence on the development of language, religion, art, architecture, literature, philosophy, law, and forms of government in its territories. Latin evolved
          into the Romance languages, while Medieval Greek became the language of the East.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="back">
      <div id="b2" class="back-content">
        <h1>he rediscovery of classical science and technology (which formed the basis for Islamic science) in medieval Europe led to the Scientific Renaissance and Scientific Revolution. Many modern legal systems, such as the Napoleonic Code, descend from
          Roman law, while Rome's republican institutions have influenced the Italian city-state republics of the medieval period, the early United States, and modern democratic republics.
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Make absolute positioned div expand parent div height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070759/make-absolute-positioned-div-expand-parent-div-height)

Comment: I'd look to create the effect without absolute positioning, though. [Search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+flip+pages+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: So basically the **book height** should be equal to the page with the max height, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Animated flip-book using CSS

[image]

Z-index in 3D CSS is a painful, bug-prone approach and should be avoided. While going 3D, account for stacking context but forget about z-index.
**Use `translate` on the `Z` axis instead.**

- To create a flip-book where the tallest page dictates the entire book height — use CSS `flex`.
- Retract (translate) each .page's `.back` to *negative 100% X*
- Retract (translate) each .book's `.page` to *negative pageIndex * 100% X*
- Now that all the pages are overlapping, stack each page in the Z axis by a negative amount of index times *"thickness"* pixels (not less than `0.4`px or the natural stacking order might transpare)
- Use JavaScript purely to assign pages index var `--i`, and change CSS var  `--c` for *current* page index. The math for transformation and animation will be handled **entirely by CSS**.

Here's a *Tl;Dr* example, where I've inclined the `.book` on the *X* axis just a bit, to make more obvious the way the pages animation actually works. For a pure top-down remove the `rotate` rule.
PS: you can also click any page edge to flip more pages at once.

```js
const flipBook = (elBook) => {
  elBook.style.setProperty("--c", 0); // Set current page
  elBook.querySelectorAll(".page").forEach((page, idx) => {
    page.style.setProperty("--i", idx);
    page.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
      const curr = evt.target.closest(".back") ? idx : idx + 1;
      elBook.style.setProperty("--c", curr);
    });
  });
};

document.querySelectorAll(".book").forEach(flipBook);
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  /* or any other parent wrapper */
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100dvh;
  perspective: 1000px;
  font: 16px/1.4 sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #232425;
}

.book {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  /*1* let pointer event go trough pages of lower Z than .book */
  pointer-events: none;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: translate 1s;
  translate: calc(min(var(--c), 1) * 50%) 0%;
  /* DEMO ONLY: incline on the X axis for pages preview */
  rotate: 1 0 0 30deg;
}

.page {
  --thickness: 5;
  /* PS: Don't go below thickness 0.4 or the pages might transpare */
  flex: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  /*1* allow pointer events on pages */
  pointer-events: all;
  user-select: none;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border: 1px solid #0008;
  transform-origin: left center;
  transition:
    transform 1s,
    rotate 1s ease-in calc((min(var(--i), var(--c)) - max(var(--i), var(--c))) * 50ms);
  translate: calc(var(--i) * -100%) 0px 0px;
  transform: translateZ( calc((var(--c) - var(--i) - 0.5) * calc(var(--thickness) * 1px)));
  rotate: 0 1 0 calc(clamp(0, var(--c) - var(--i), 1) * -180deg);
}

.page img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.front,
.back {
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* Fix backface visibility Firefox: */
  translate: 0px;
}

.back {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 80%, #ddd 100%);
  translate: -100% 0;
  rotate: 0 1 0 180deg;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="front">
      <h1>FlipBook</h1>
      <h3>2023.<br>Second edition</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, modi, perspiciatis molestias cum neque delectus eum eveniet repellat iusto totam magnam cupiditate quaerat quis.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="page">
    <div class="front">
      2. Dolor Molestias aspernatur repudiandae sed quos debitis recusandae consectetur ab facilis voluptates sint vero eos, consequuntur delectus?
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/400" alt="Img 1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="page">
    <div class="front">
      <h2>Sit amet</h2>
      4. Consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos illo voluptate sapiente provident tempore ea voluptates perferendis tenetur eos nulla, doloribus! Distinctio a nostrum ipsum, adipisci at mollitia.
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      5. Debitis recusandae consectetur ab facilis voluptates sint vero eos, consequuntur delectus temporibus harum dolorem provident eaque perferendis.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="page">
    <div class="front">
      <h2>Consectetur</h2>
      6. Adipisicing elit. Sed, fuga aspernatur? Numquam, molestias unde! Voluptatibus sint aspernatur qui dolore est itaque ipsum consequuntur neque asperiores non obcaecati harum, perspiciatis voluptate!
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      7. Temporibus, eum nobis? Adipisci, a? Eaque vel amet ut reprehenderit.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="page">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Img 2">
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <h3>Finalis</h3>
      9. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. code by Roko, eniam vero, magni dignissimos deleniti hic ratione sequi ullam eos.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tip:
If you want to create a navigation with buttons all you need to do is to change the *"current page"* CSS `--c` var via JavaScript like:

```js
// On navigation button click:
elBook.style.setProperty("--c", someIndex);
```

and the book will animate automagically to the desired page-view.

---

Git project: https://github.com/rokobuljan/flipbook

Comment: Wow! This is so good! So essentially you used `page.style.translate = ${-100 * pageIndex}% 0;` in Javascript to simulate the `absolute` property? Ingenious! Thank you so much, this is the best example of a book with flipping pages I've seen!

Comment: I struggled with making `zIndex` work right, especially when taking into account the time it takes for a page to flip over. Your `transitionend` event listener works flawlessly!

Comment: Wow, thank you! I didn't think it would is possible, as all examples in the Internet use `z-index`!

Comment: @parsecer exactly. Z-index is just not the way to approach 3D in HTMl/CSS. After hours of experimenting and head scratching - edited with a rock-solid solution.

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could give more than one upvote! Your solution helped me a lot, and I'm sure it'll have many others who'll find this answer! Maybe you should upload it as a js/vue/react/etc library to some repositories, as there don't seem to be many solutions of comparable quality out there!

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like this version doesn't work in Google Chrome properly. Works in Brave and Firefox... I tried the StackOverflow code snippet and a codepen, both appear messed up in Google Chrome ; (

Comment: @parsecer opened (this SO code snippet) in Chrome  (Version 112.0.5615.138 (Official Build) (64-bit) (Windows 11)) and works flawlessly just like in Brave, Firefox and Edge

Comment: @RokoC.Bulijan It is probably the Chrome's version (` 97.0.4692.99`), not sure why, as it's only one year old ; (

Comment: One issue I've noticed and couldn't fix despite much googling is the blurry text in the pages ; ( Wasn't sure at first, but it really looks the font in the book pages is more blurry than in a normal div, and it's especially visible in a dark theme styling: https://codepen.io/sabeser/pen/abPWpxp. I tried adding styles like `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiase`, but it did nothing ; ( It looks like the font, getting blurry during the flipping, never quite comes the full way back to the original focus

Comment: @parsecer that issue is something I was not able to get right for a long time. whatever you find online seems to be of no help. As soon we add `perspective` to a parent (being `.book` or as in the demo: `body`) the text becomes blurry in Chromium-based browsers. I'm not sure what's the exact balance of CSS properties, or a bullet-proof solution to this in 2023... Sadly. Will research and test. So far any trick I could find was of no help.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should have done this using JavaScript.
Calc every page height when the content is changed (you should get height of p1 div) and set it to height of book.
You can get the height of content using this:

```
const book = document.getElementById('book');
... ... ...
book.style.height = element.querySelector('h1').offsetHeight;
```

The main thing is, update the book div's height when showing content changes.

Comment: Is a pure CSS solution not possible though?

Comment: I think a solution with CSS only is wanted.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the element to have a minimum height in px, but with the possibility to shrink when the content is larger.

To achive that, instead of using `height`, set a **minimum height**.

```
min-height: 500px;
```

Comment: It won't work when the content doesn't fit even `500px` and a higher height is needed

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? If the content needs higher height, it will be higher.

Comment: It won't because of `absolute` position

Comment: Well then don't use absolute position. I don't see any reason to use it in your case

Comment: I will. Sorry for the missunderstanding.